# How to read tactile sensor data from gazebo?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a small project where I have to develop a custom control plugin and test it on gazebo simulation. In my Gazebo robot model I am using sr_tactile-sensors, Now I need to use that sensor output in my custom control plugin, can anyone suggest me how to do that ? I am quite new to qazebo. I am writing my control plugin in python. Would be really helpful if you can point me in the direction where I can find details about the same, I have been trying to google it myself. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321262/how-to-read-tactile-sensor-data-from-gazebo-?/) by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-17**:
If you check the [`sr_tactile_sensors` wiki page](https://wiki.ros.org/sr_tactile_sensors#Published_Topics), it shows what topics that package publishes. Is that what you're asking or are you asking *how* to subscribe to those topics?

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-04-17**:
yea exactly, I am asking how to subscribe them

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-17**:
You should go through the [beginner tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node) and see if this helps. If it doesn't, then please update your question with a copy and paste of your code and any errors that may arise, along with what you don't understand.

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-04-17**:
Thank you for the tutorial. Although I have seen it before, I have not understood how to write the similar listener for sr_tactile_sensors, so as far as I understand i should import sensor_msgs package and then the specific sr_tactile_sensors package aswell and then use those pre-defined commands to access the sensor data ? or should I write a specific  code for it ? I have not startd writing the code for this particular part as I am still confused and did not know where to start this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a [set of tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/sr_tactile_sensors) on the [`sr_tactile_sensors` wiki page](https://wiki.ros.org/sr_tactile_sensors/Tutorials/Getting%20Data) that may help you. For example, there's one that shows [how to subscribe to the `/sr_tactile/touch/ff` topic](https://wiki.ros.org/sr_tactile_sensors/Tutorials/Getting%20Data#Accessing_the_data_in_a_different_node). It's in C++ so I made a Python version of it (that's been combined with the [subscriber tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64


def callback(msg):
    # log the message data to the terminal
    rospy.loginfo("The value is %d", msg.data)


def listener():
    # start the node
    rospy.init_node("listener")
    # subscribe to the '/sr_tactile/touch/ff' topic
    tactile_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/sr_tactile/touch/ff", Float64, callback)
    # keep python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [microbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/39013/microbot/) on 2019-04-20**:
Thank you very much, this is indeed helpful.